# MongoDB database creation with spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am creating a sample web application with spring 3.0 and mongoDB. Following is my root-context.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <import resource="classpath:mongo-config.xml"/>

</beans>
```

and my mongo-config.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo'. write concern set to SAFE to ensure unique indexes -->
    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017" write-concern="SAFE"/>

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.dashboard.repositories" />

    <bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="DASHBOARD"/>
        <constructor-arg name="credentials" ref="userCredentials"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
        <property name="writeResultChecking">
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION" ></util:constant>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="test"/>
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="abc123"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

when i start the tomcat server, there is no database "Dashboard" created. What is wrong with this code, Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to insert anything with your application. Unlike RDMS Mongo does not create a database schema upfront.

Comment: yes when i add user with signup form, it creates db and add user to it. But should it create a database as soon as the server starts and initialize the mongoDbFactory bean.

Comment: Check this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#do-mongodb-databases-have-schemas Schemas are dynamic and heterogenous so mongo cannot create a fixed schema as RDMS before inserting any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making it visible to other viewers i will put my comment into the answer. In Mongo schemas are dynamic and heterogenous so mongo cannot create a fixed schema as RDMS before inserting any data. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#do-mongodb-databases-have-schemas) is a more detailed explanation.